# Restore but still in deleted list, use mongoose-delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When I delete a data in my list, the properties of this data are switched to true, deleted & move to the trash. But when I go to trash and click restore, the properties deleted are no longer available and the data reappear in the list, but it still appears in the trash and doesn't go away.
How can I fix it?

https://github.com/tienlehung1080/nodejs_test

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you need to add an if statement in trash-courses.hbs:

```
{{#each course}}
    {{#if deleted}}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{sum @index 1}}</th>
          <td>{{this.name}}</td>
          <td>{{this.level}}</td>
          <td>{{this.createdAt}}</td>
          <td>
            <a
              href=""
              class="btn btn-link btn-restore"
              data-id="{{this._id}}"
            >Restore</a>
            <a
              href=""
              class="btn btn-link"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-id="{{this._id}}"
              data-target="#delete-course-modal"
            >Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}
    {{else}}
       <tr>
         <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
            Empty.
           <a href="/me/stored/courses">Back to course list</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
{{/each}}
```

In the updated code, the {{#if deleted}} statement is added within the {{#each}} block. It checks if the deleted property of each course is true, and if so, it renders the table row for that course. This ensures that only courses with deleted: true will be displayed in the table.

> the properties deleted are no longer available

This is expected behavior. After restore is called, the deleted property is removed.

Hope this helps!